# How to pass array of datetime from vue.js to an ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#, api, vue.js

My API code

```
[HttpGet("/GetBusinessDaysWithPublicHolidayDates/")]
public int GetBusinessDays(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate,[FromQuery] IList<DateTime> publicHolidays)
{
    var noOfDays = _dayCalculatorService.BusinessDaysBetweenTwoDates(startDate, endDate, publicHolidays);

    return noOfDays;
}
```

My API call from Vue js code:

```
var arr = JSON.stringify(this.publicHolidays);

axios.get('https://localhost:7054/GetBusinessDaysWithPublicHolidayDates', {
    params: {
      startDate: this.startdate,
      endDate:this.enddate,
      publicHolidays:JSON.parse(arr)
```

URL is created in this format:

```
https://localhost:7054/GetBusinessDaysWithPublicHolidayDates?publicHolidays[]=2022-06-16T14:39:00.000Z&publicHolidays[]=2022-06-20T14:39:00.000Z
```

But API is working with this URL:

```
https://localhost:7054/GetBusinessDaysWithPublicHolidayDates?publicHolidays=2022-06-16T14:39:00.000Z&publicHolidays=2022-06-20T14:39:00.000Z
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the date and time as an array using JSON.stringify.

```
this.$axios.get('/GetBusinessDaysWithPublicHolidayDates/', {
  params: {
    q: JSON.stringify(result)
  }
})
```

And URL for the API call will get created as

```
http://localhost:7054/cidade/?q=[value1,value2]
```